# Mongoose/MongoDB batchSize(30) still returning all results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The following query returns all my users. I was hoping it would be batched.

```
statics.findAllUsers = function findAllUsers(callback) {
  this.find({}, callback).batchSize(30);
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to place `batchSize` before `find`? Like this: `this.batchSize(30).find({}, callback);`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: tried that but got Unexpected errorObject function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'batchSize'

Comment: Are you sure you don't want [`limit(30)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) instead?

Comment: i could use limit(30), yes, but that does not work either.

Comment: It will if you use it right:  `this.find({}).limit(30).exec(callback);`. Or are you expecting your callback to be called multiple times, each with 30 docs?

Comment: ah ok so limit worked using the above but would i be able to get the next 30 using limit?

Comment: You'd have to call it again, but also adding `skip(30)` this time, to skip the ones you got last time.

Comment: @JohnnyHK You mean calling the query again? If yes then same query will be executed till your all docs are sent. Can't this be done in a single query? Like send docs in chunks - 30,30,30....till last.

Answer (score 5):

`batchSize()` instructs the driver to retrieve a certain number of items per time. It'll still get everything from the DB, only a batch at a time.

To make it clearer: If you use `batchSize(30)` then it'll ask for 30 items then, when you need the 31st, it'll query the next 30 and so forth.

If you need only that number of items, then use `limit()` (and `offset()` to set which is the first item)

Docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/